# How to organize one step after another in Azure Machine Learning Pipelines?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have defined an Azure Machine Learning Pipeline with three steps:

```
e2e_steps=[etl_model_step, train_model_step, evaluate_model_step]
e2e_pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps = e2e_steps)
```

The idea is to run the Pipeline in the given sequence:

1. etl_model_step
2. train_model_step
3. evaluate_model_step

However, my experiment is failing because it is trying to execute evaluate_model_step before train_model_step:
[image]

How do I enforce the sequence of execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`azureml.pipeline.core.StepSequence` lets you do exactly that.

> A StepSequence can be used to easily run steps in a specific order, without needing to specify data dependencies through the use of PipelineData.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.stepsequence?view=azure-ml-py) to read more.

However, the preferable way to have steps run in order is stitching them together via `PipelineData` or `OutputFileDatasetConfig`. In your example, does the `train_step` depend on outputs from the `etl step`? If so, consider having that be the way that steps are run in sequence. For more info see [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-move-data-in-out-of-pipelines) for more info

Comment: Step Sequence looks like a better alternative to `step2.run_after(step1)`

Comment: yeah but really you should be using `PIpelineData` are there not data dependency between the steps? how is the data from the etl step made available to the train step??

Comment: What I did was to register the final dataset in the ETL step as an AzML Dataset Asset, and then refer to it by name in the next steps.

Comment: ok. then definitely check out the tutorial linked above. if you adopt that approach you'll get to use the `PythonScriptStep`'s `allow_reuse` param which is an awesome, time-saving feature

Comment: Only if second step is dependent on the data generated by the first step, PipelineData or OutputFileDatasetConfig is useful.